# Flutter Could not resolve all file for configuration ':qr_code_scanner:coreLibraryDesugaring'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-studio, gradle

I have a prorject that I have to use [QrCodeScanner](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner)

When I Add this package in Pubspec `qr_code_scanner: ^1.0.1`
I can't build my project

This is the error I get when syncing my project:

```
    A build operation failed.
    Could not resolve all files for configuration ':qr_code_scanner:coreLibraryDesugaring'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':qr_code_scanner:coreLibraryDesugaring'.
Failed to transform desugar_jdk_libs-1.2.0.jar (com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.0) to match attributes {artifactType=_internal-desugar-lib-lint, lint-compile-sdk=32, lint-min-sdk=20, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
Could not find desugar_jdk_libs-1.2.0.jar (com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.0).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/desugar_jdk_libs/1.2.0/desugar_jdk_libs-1.2.0.jar
```

Gradle Versions :

```
Gradle-7.6-all.zip
gralde-tools-7.1.2
```

Flutter Doctor :

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2428], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.16)
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.83.1)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources
```

Comment: Not necessarily a fix to this particular bug, but you should know that qr_code_scanner is in maintenance mode as its underlying dependencies are no longer being worked on (ZXing and MTBBarcodeScanner). The developer recommends switching to mobile_scanner https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_scanner.